# How to draw in a canvas

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to draw in a canvas some of the elements that i need for my code and I was asking myself if I can get some examples codes from you (for example how to draw a line on a canvas) . Thank for your time.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: as i said, i'm new to this approach, so i don't know what to do, and i'm searching for examples codes from other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:-

`<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">`

Javascript:-

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.stroke();
```